# VTune did not launch application correctly

Tags: intel, profiler, intel-vtune

When profiling remotely, Intel VTune seems can't start application correctly.

I configure my target as a `.sh` script [my vtune launch app config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVF5x.png).
And the amplex-python shows that The script successful launch, but not the app. why?[amplex-python window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74DTd.png)
here is my `.sh` script:

```sh
MPIRUN=/opt/intel/oneapi/mpi/latest/bin/

SRC_DIR=$(pwd)
#make clean
#make -j8

cd ..
ROOT_DIR=$(pwd)
echo "SRC_DIR:"$SRC_DIR
echo "ROOT_DIR:"$ROOT_DIR

cd $SRC_DIR
# $MPIRUN/mpirun -n 64 -host 1ibHost,3ibHost -env UCX_TLS=ud_verbs,ud_mlx5 /home/inspur/nfsIPCC/myprog 
$MPIRUN/mpirun -n 108 -host 1ibHost,3ibHost -env UCX_TLS=ud_verbs,ud_mlx5 $SRC_DIR/main 0.005  $ROOT_DIR/data/ipcc_gauge_24_72  24 24 24 72  8 8 8 18
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a shell script as a target application to profile by VTune, you need to add [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) at the begging of the script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
MPIRUN=/opt/intel/oneapi/mpi/latest/bin/

SRC_DIR=$(pwd)
#make clean
#make -j8

cd ..
ROOT_DIR=$(pwd)
echo "SRC_DIR:"$SRC_DIR
echo "ROOT_DIR:"$ROOT_DIR

cd $SRC_DIR
# $MPIRUN/mpirun -n 64 -host 1ibHost,3ibHost -env UCX_TLS=ud_verbs,ud_mlx5 /home/inspur/nfsIPCC/myprog 
$MPIRUN/mpirun -n 108 -host 1ibHost,3ibHost -env UCX_TLS=ud_verbs,ud_mlx5 $SRC_DIR/main 0.005  $ROOT_DIR/data/ipcc_gauge_24_72  24 24 24 72  8 8 8 18
```

It is required by `execve()` and described in the [description section](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).
Also please note that according to the documentation, `vtune` command should be run using `mpirun`:

```
mpirun [options] vtune [options] <program> [<args>]
```

It is described in [Configure MPI Analysis with the VTune Profiler](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/vtune-help/top/analyze-performance/code-profiling-scenarios/mpi-code-analysis.html#mpi-code-analysis_GUID-DA95128C-9B72-4445-A22B-C77CB4354F9F) help topic.